# Find the closure for this topological space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

$X = (0,\infty)$ and $S_n = (0, 1/n) \cup (n,n+1)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Let the topological space $(X,T)$ having the subbasis, $S_n$

Find the  closure of the $A$$(=({\frac{1}{4}},{\frac{1}{2}} ))$

Try to find the closure $\bar{A}$, I found the derived set, $A'$

So $A' = [1/4,1)$ $\cup $ $(1,2)$ $\cup $ $(2,3)$ $\cup $ $(3,4) \cup \mathbb{N}$

The reason why the $\mathbb{N} \subset A'$ is
$X$ is the only open set including each $n$. (Here the $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$)

Hence my answer is $\bar A = [1/4,4] \cup \mathbb{N}$

But the answer was $\bar A = [1/4,4]$ in my lecturer's note.

Is my answer is right? I don't understand why the answer is $\bar A = [1/4,4]$